# Google signing an app in by using a webview

Tags: android, web-applications, android-webview, google-oauth

I am trying to open my mobile responsive website in an android APK in web-view. It has sign-in with Google, which works well on a desktop or mobile bowser. But not working in android web-view.
"OAuth doesn't work in web-view" says Google error message.

[image: screenshot of the error]

So how can I achieve Google sign-in in a web view based app? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Refer to the error message. Only browsers can be part of the Google authentication process for users. This is a security policy deployed by Google Accounts.

You will need to create a standard OAuth 2.0 Flow. Here is a document to get you started.

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Comment: Is there any reference about your statement `Only browsers can be part of the Google authentication process for users.`?

Comment: I don't remember where that is documented. It is and you will not find anywhere a document showing how to authenticate users without the browser. Google has special code to detect and block attempts to circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a user agent for your Android WebView using below code. You can use whatever string you want.

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("yor-user-agent-string");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html